# Android notification when sql row is added

Tags: android, sql

How would one go about creating a notification when a row is added to a remote SQL server?

For example, if user A inserts a row into the SQL table via a PHP script is there a way for user B to get some sort of response from the server to know to display a notification something has been added to the database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to check GCM http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the underlying database (I've only done it in mySQL and Interbase/Firebird), there's usually a mechanism available to have an update/insert trigger either update another table (which you could pull) or broadcast a message on a socket (which could then generate a notification).

That said, a good web application is build around a framework, and those frameworks usually abstract the database interaction. In short, find the spot in the php script where the row is inserted, and hook your notification code in there. It'll be much more reliable, and more instantaneous.

As far as notifying the remote application, you might want to look into [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Just started reading the documentation, looks promising. Thanks!